# thumb drive to authenticate user using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, usb-drive

I'm currently working on a project using visual studio 2010. I will like to know how to use a thumb drive to authenticate security in asp.net.

For example, when you insert a thumb drive from the user computer(example D: drive). The system is able to track that this is the correct drive plus the thumb drive and then the user will be able to view the page. If the thumb drive is removed or not insert, it will redirect you to a lock.aspx screen till the thumb drive is inserted back again to the correct drive.

I am thinking using the serial number as the key to know which is the thumb drive.

It is something like the (USB predator) but I am trying to do it on a web application instead on Windows.

Anyone can give me a guide on how to start or tools that I can use for this?

Comment: I don't think any client browsers are going to be able to interact with thumb drives.  You will need custom software that runs on the client to make it work.  Are you OK with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem consists of two parts.

First, you need to have something on the client which will check the USB device. Browsers themselves won't do this for you unless you have a power to build some custom version of the browser (Chromium- or Mozilla-based, for example) and have your users install and use this browser. Alternatively you can create a plugin for the browser, which will do the job. One more option is to have some applet on each page of your service. In case of plugin you need to have the client install it and the plugin host itself (browser) should let the applet connect to USB device in some way. In case of applet see below.

Second aspect is the use of the USB drive. Such drives can be easily copied or stolen, so their security is low. There exist USB cryptotokens, designed as part of their functionality for client-side authentication, the task similar to yours. USB cryptotokens contain certificates with private keys and/or they can contain symmetric keys or other information which (A) requires the user to enter PIN to access this information and (B) is not extractable from the device (keys can be used but not copied). Both A and B significantly increase security.

USB cryptotokens require that the user installs the driver for such token, also the tokens are more expensive than regular flash memory. On the other hand, they can be accessed from Java applets relatively easily (and maybe from browser plugins too - this depends on the browser) AND they can be used for authentication in a safe way by performing cryptographic operations instead of pure transfer of the serial number or alike.

To sum up, you can build a login scheme but you will need to make the user install something (plugin and/or USB token driver or custom browser).

Comment: Hi, I have a better understanding after I read your comment. Thanks.